# Do we have to use partial fraction to find Laurent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, laurent-series, partial-fractions

Is there a way other than the use of partial fractions to find the Laurent series of $$\frac{z+1}{z(z-4)^3}$$ in the region $0<|z-4|<4$?

Comment: The other way I could think up of is to use the definition directly, that the coefficients are integrations. But it is not practical

Comment: From the Laurent series, the partial fraction decomposition will be obvious, so no there is no other way. However, you can multiply (without simplifying) the Laurent series for each factor, it will be ugly but correct.